# Django Attribute error on serializer when using intermediate model

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I've been trying to create a serializer for a Model in which one of the fields is a ManytoManyField through a Model that adds more fields. The problem is that the intermediate serializer is not recognizing that has added fields. Why could I be doing wrong?

Here is my code:

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

class Movement(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='Movement_Product')

class Movement_Product(models.Model):
    movement = models.ForeignKey(Movement)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)

class Input(Movement):
    invoice_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
```

serializers.py:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Product

class MovementProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer()
    price = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    amount = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Movement_Product

class InputSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date = serializers.DateTimeField()
    products = MovementProductSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Input
```

views.py:

```
class InputViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Input.objects.order_by('-date')
    serializer_class = InputSerializer
```

urls.py:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'input', views.InputViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

The error I got when I try to render the InputSerializer on URL path in my browser http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/input/:

> Attribute Error at /api/input/
>
> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `product` on serializer `MovementProductSerializer`.
>
> The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Product` instance.
>
> Original exception text was: 'Product' object has no attribute 'product'.

Comment: Post urls.py and also request parameters which you are passing.

Comment: Done. I'm passing no parameters, it is just a GET to /api/input/, also this failing only when there is data in Input model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
class Movement(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='Movement_Product')

    @property
    def movement_product(self):
        return Movement_Product.objects.filter(movement=self)

class InputSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date = serializers.DateTimeField()
    products = serializers.ListField(child=MovementProductSerializer(), source='movement_product')

    class Meta:
        model = Input
```

Comment: It says 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable

Comment: add a param `through_fields=('movement', 'product')` to `products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='Movement_Product')` in class Movement

Comment: You mean like this: `products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='Movement_Product', through_fields=('movement', 'product'))` still the same :(

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. This is my last attempt, please change the InputSerializer's model to Movement.

Comment: Still no useful

Comment: Now it is not returning errors, but the products are not being listed `[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "date": "2017-03-15T14:54:50.992585Z",
        "invoice_number": null
    }
]`

Comment: I edit my answer again. If you want to display product and price and amount in products list, you can do like this. If you just want to display product in product list, you should change `products = MovementProductSerializer(many=True)` to `products = ProductSerializer(many=True)`